# Заменить в каждом нечётной строке матрицы все чётные по значению элементы нулём

Tags: c#, .net

1)Есть матрица, размерность которой задает пользователь(int[,] matrix = new int[size, size]) - сделано.
2)Матрица генерируется с-100 до 100 - сделано.
3)Вывод матрицы - сделано.
4)Нужно: Заменить в каждом нечётной СТРОКЕ матрицы (начиная с нулевого) все чётные по значению элементы нулём.
5)Вывод новой матрицы - сделано
Помогите пожалуйста с 4ым пунктом

Код ниже делает замену отрицательных элементов на 0 в в четных столбцах.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите размер матрицы: ");
        bool ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int size);

        if (size < 0 || size > 7)
            throw new Exception("Введены невалидные данные!");

        int[,] matrix = new int[size, size];
        Random generator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = generator.Next(-100, 100);
                Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");  
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0 && matrix[i, j] < 0)
                    matrix[i, j] = 0;
                Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Результат работы программы:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i = i + 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i, j] % 2 == 0)
                matrix[i, j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: этот код не работает
https://imgurhd.ru/6k0b

Comment: @Student Мой код не может дать такой результат. Вы неаккуратно скопировали его к себе.

Comment: Его можно не копировать, а просто изменить строчки моего кода.
Изображение ниже
https://sun9-65.userapi.com/c857332/v857332893/130266/JZMZy0_W0ds.jpg
https://sun9-42.userapi.com/c857332/v857332893/13026d/1Qo7Z4PJ3YQ.jpg

Comment: @Student попробуйте все таки скопировать.

Comment: @Student Это не мой код.

Comment: Мне нужно вставить ваши 4 цикла на место двух моих последних?

Comment: @Student Два моих блока вместо последнего Вашего.

Comment: @Igor https://sun9-2.userapi.com/c857332/v857332893/13027f/J6p3BFbcXzI.jpg
https://sun9-24.userapi.com/c857332/v857332893/130286/WVkrnN-jm5I.jpg

Comment: @Igor Все равно не работает или я "туплю"

Comment: @Student Вы "тупите". Что "не работает"?

Comment: @Igor в НЕЧЕТНЫХ строках, т.е 1 3 5 и т.д заменить ЧЕТНЫЕ элементы на ноль

Comment: @Student на вашей последней картинке именно это и сделано

Comment: @Student Это то, что делает мой код. Вероятно, Вы называете первой строкой строку с индексом 0. Тогда напишите: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 2)`

Comment: @Igor Я знаю, что элементы массива индексируются с 0, но не думал, что в данном случае так нужно. Извините, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Student Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.